# Addressables not working in smaller Unity build

Tags: unity-game-engine, asset-pipeline, addressables

I'm working on a Unity project where I have implemented the Addressables system. However, I'm facing an issue where sometimes, when I get a player build with a smaller size than the average build, Addressables don't seem to be working properly in that build.

Here are the details of my project setup and the issue I'm experiencing:

Unity version: 2020.3.24f1
Target platform: Android
Addressables package version: 1.19.4
Build size difference: The problematic build is about 1 mb smaller than the average build size.

I've already tried the following troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists:

Checked the build settings and asset bundle assignments for missing assets.
Verified the compression settings in the Addressables profile.
Ensured the correct platform settings are selected.
Confirmed the runtime settings and load paths for Addressables are properly configured.
Checked for network or server issues with remote asset bundles.
Cleared Addressables caches and rebuilt asset bundles.
Reviewed my scripts for any logic errors or incorrect usage of Addressables APIs.
Changed Addressables version up and down.
Despite these efforts, I'm still facing the issue, and I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to identify and resolve this issue. If you need any additional information, please let me know, and I'll be happy to provide it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What errors do you have in case of "smaller Unity build"? And how exactly your addressables "don't seem to be working properly"?

Comment: Average build size is 98 mb but problematic one 97 mb. There is 1 mb gap. it is like there is no addressables implementation. The URL queries return null.I mean catalog can not be loaded.

Comment: I solved the issue. if catalog files were deleted, build would failed. You should not delete catalog files before player build.